# C++: Access members of struct via a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I run in to segmentation faults when running this code (no compiler warnings or errors).
It occurs when trying to assign "Test" to `str->sString`

```
MyClass.cpp
//Constructor
MyClass::MyClass( MyStruct *pDesc )
{   
    pDesc = new MyStruct();

    //This is where I get a segmentation fault  
    pDesc->bar= 0xFF;   

}


MyClass.hpp

class ClGadgetFs
{
    public:
            struct MyStruct{
        int bar;
        };
       MyClass(MyStruct *pDesc = NULL);
};
```

I thought when calling new I would be aalocating memory for the struct? Like `malloc(sizeof(myStruct))` 
Where am I wrong?

Comment: If you're passing a pointer that's already valid, why allocate memory for it?

Comment: please provide the real code, this is not it.

Comment: Please provide a complete, compilable and executable example which displays the problem you describe.

Comment: appart the `sStrnig` typo your code should work. As other people says, it wont have any effect outside of the method but this is another topic.

Comment: You needn't `malloc` since you're already using `new`. Former is the C way of allocating dynamic memory while the latter is (safer) C++ way of allocating dynamic memory.

Comment: Edited for more detailed code.

Comment: @tzippy: Yes for that you need to have the argument as a pointer to a pointer and not just a pointer. You need to understand dynamic memory and pointer semantics better before diving in further.

Answer (score 4):

```
void setStruct(myStruct *str)
{
   str->sString = "Test";
   str->nNo = 4;
}

int main()
{
    myStruct p;
    setStruct(&p);
    return 0;
}
```

you can do this instead

**Edit**

```
int main()
{
   MyStruct *pDesc;
   MyClass myClassInstance( pDesc );
   std::cout<< pDesc->bar << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

and

```
MyClass::MyClass( MyStruct *pDesc )
```

should be changed to

```
MyClass::MyClass( MyStruct *& pDesc )
```

Comment: that's clean and means you don't need to worry about deallocating memory.

Comment: plus, you only send a pointer to a class, not the whole structure.

Answer (score 2):

```
void setStruct(myStruct*& str)
```

The above is probably what you want: changing the passed pointer, as output parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>

struct myStruct
{
   std::string sString;
   int nNo;
};


void setStruct(myStruct **str)
{
   *str = new myStruct();
   (*str)->sString = "Test";
   (*str)->nNo = 4;
}

int main()
{
    myStruct *p;
    setStruct(&p);
}
```

should be what you want, this is the C-style of passing the pointer; since you're allocating memory for the passed pointer, passing the pointer alone doesn't work, you should pass the pointer's address. Another way would be a reference to the pointer that Joop Eggen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17089125/183120) points out.

Answer (score 0):

`str` in the function `setStruct` is a local variable, whose life time is limited in this function.

So when `new` returns the address, there is no effect on the actual parameter. It is just the same to

```
void func(int a){
     a = 4
}
```

You should use pointer to pointer or reference

```
void setStruct(myStruct ** str){
    (*str) = new myStruct();
    (*str)->sString = "Test";
    (*str)->nNo = 4;
}

void setStruct(myStruct *& str){
    str = new myStruct();
    str->sString = "Test";
    str->nNo = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the caller of `setStruct` is allocating a `myStruct` *on the stack*:

```
myStruct value;
```

and you are calling `setStruct(&value);`

That would cause the segmentation fault as you would be attempting to rearrange the stack memory.
It's difficult to say anything else without the complete example though.

There's nothing wrong with the code as it stands aside from the fact that the value of the pointer following `str = new myStruct();` is not passed back to the caller: the caller would be still referring to the pointer pointing to unallocated memory which would result in *undefined behaviour*. But that is *not* causing your crash since given where you say the error happens.

A simple fix would be to change the function prototype to

```
void setStruct(myStruct*& str)
```

i.e. pass the pointer by reference so the caller get's the modified pointer value back.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a reference to your pointer to modify it in your function:

```
struct myStruct{
    std::string sStrnig;
    int nNo;
};


void setStruct(myStruct* &str){

    str = new myStruct();

    str->sString = "Test";
    str->nNo = 4;
}

main(){
    struct myStruct *str = 0;
    setStruct( str );
}
```